# Restrict access to iOS built-in application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icons

I'm interested in a way to restrict access to the build-in iOS applications(Settings,Calendar,Contacts,etc).

I've seen a lot of solutions but i don't want to jailbreak my devices.Also, the "Restrictions" setting isn't enought since it only blocks a few apps.

Could be anything from removing the icon or setting a passcode to access it.

Thanks,
Cearnau Dan

Comment: This would be an admin question, *not* a programming question. You can't do this with any part of the SDK, and I'm glad you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a passcode to access the device, but not for individual applications, and there's not built in way to hide icons that I'm aware of. Your only option is to jailbreak it or live with them not being restricted.